# Angular 2 datatables will cause issues with ng4?

Tags: angular, datatables, grid

I have to choose a datatable/grid for my project with many features included in it,such as filtering,sorting,inline editing,large datasets handling ,touch capability,responsive,error handling,hierarichal display etc.But  most of the time i end up with a table that is being written for angular 2.Those which i find for angular 4 are sill in RC.So in my opinion i think i can go with those angular 2 datatables and grids.Am i right? or they will create issues later, down the lane of my project.Can you guys help me out,and showcase areas that i am overshadowing now. Finally whether i should go with angular 2 datatables/grid or ng4 table compatibility.

Comment: can any one mention why my question is given negative marks?

Comment: This is a valid question, not sure why it was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like ng2-datatables is being actively supported anymore so in the long run you should upgrade to ng4-datatables and use that going forward since that is the one that is being actively supported. That goes for most situations when it comes to Angular btw.

Comment: Hi kevin,i have been able to integrate ng2-datatables which are available online such as ngx-datatable,primeng datatable,ag-grid free version in my Angular 4 project setups.Can you highlight some issues,which i might face while going with these ng2 datatables in future.Thanks in advance!